# Retrieve data from txt file and replace the data into a new txt file using java

Tags: java

I am trying to read in a text file and then manipulate a little and update the records into a new text file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
ArrayList<String> linesList = new ArrayList<>();

BufferedReader br;

String empid, email;

String[] data;

try {
    String line;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
        linesList.add(line);
    }
    br.close();
}
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

for (int i = 0; i < linesList.size(); i++) {
    data = linesList.get(i).split(",");
    empid = data[0];
    ccode = data[3];
}
File tempFile = new File("File2.txt");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
for (int i = 0; i < linesList.size(); i++) {
    if(i==0){
        bw.write(linesList.get(i));
        bw.newLine();
    }
    else{
        data = linesList.get(i).split(",");

        String empid1 = data[0];
        if(data[13].equals("IND")) {
            String replace = data[3].replaceAll("IND", "IN");
            ccode1 = replace;
            System.out.println(ccode1); 
        }
        else if(data[13].equals("USA")) {
            String replace = data[3].replaceAll("USA", "US");
            ccode1 = replace;
        }
        else {
            ccode1 = replace; //This does not work as replace is not defined here, but how can I get it to work here.
        }
        String newData=empid1+","+ccode1;
        bw.write(newData);
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
```

Here is what is inside the text file:

```
EID,First,Last,Country
1,John,Smith,USA
2,Jane,Smith,IND
3,John,Adams,USA
```

So, what I need help with is editing the three letter country code and replacing it with a 2 letter country code. For example: USA would become US, and IND would become IN. I am able to read in the country code, but am having trouble in changing the value and then replacing the changed value back into a different text file. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a pain doing manually, I'd recommend you to do not 'reinvent the wheel' so use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: In order to "edit" a file, you need to actually write the lines back out to the same filename.

Comment: If your most significant problem is mapping one value to another and both sets are well-defined, then you can use a `HashMap`. If all you want to do is translate the country code by taking only its first 2 characters, then you can do it with `String.substring`. My guess is that if you further qualify your question, then you might get more effective help.

Answer (score 0):

Open file in text editor, Search and Replace, `,USA` with `,US`, `,IND` with `,IN` and so on.

As such, to automate it, on the same while loop you read a line do:

`//while(read){ line.replaceAll(",USA",",US");`

That will be the easiest way to complete your objective.

To save, open a `BufferedWriter bw;` just like you opened a reader and use `bw.write()`. You would probably prefer to open both at the same time, the reader on your source file, and the writer on a new file, with `_out` suffix. That way you dont need to keep the file data in memory, you can read and write as you loop.

For harder ways, read the csv specs: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2

Notice that you have to account for the possibility of fields being enclosed in quotes, like: `"1","John","Smith","USA"`, which means you also have to replace `,\"USA` with `,\"US`.

The delimiter may or may not be a comma, you have to make sure yur input will always use the same delimiter, or that you can detect and switch at runtime.

You have to account for the case where a delimiter may be part of a field, or where quotes are part of a field.

Now you know/can solve these issues you can, instead of using replace, parse the lines character by character using `while( (/*int*/ c = br.read()) != -1)`, and do this replacement manually with an if gate.

```
/*while(read)*/
if( c == delimiter ){ 
    if not field, start next field, else add to field value

} else if( c == quote ){
    if field value empty, ignore and expect closing quote, else if quote escape not marked, mark it, else, add quote to field value
} 
(...)
} else if( c == 13 or c == 10 ){
    finished line, check last field of row read and replace data
}
```

To make it better/harder, define a parsing state machine, put the states into an Enum, and write the if gates with them in mind (this will make your code be more like a compiler parser).

You can find parsing code at different stages here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Comment: Where to add `line.replaceAll("USA", "US");` in the code so that replaces country code in the text file for USA occurrences in the file?

Comment: Also, if I write to the same file, will it not rewrite the whole file?

Comment: thats why you are holding the lines on the list `linelist.add( line.replaceAll(...) ) `, so you can write everything as it was, you probably want to write to a slightly different named file though

Comment: I do not want to store the changed country code in a different file, but in the same file

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a little bit in your concept. If you want to edit a file then,
create a new file and write content in new file and delete old file and rename new file 
with old name.

```
ArrayList<String> linesList = new ArrayList<>();

        BufferedReader br;
        String[] data;
        File original=new File("D:\\abc\\file.txt");
        try {
            String line;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(original));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
                linesList.add(line);
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        File tempFile = new File("D:\\abc\\tempfile.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
        for (int i = 0; i < linesList.size(); i++) {
            if(i==0){
                bw.write(linesList.get(i));
                bw.newLine();
            }
            else{
            data = linesList.get(i).split(",");
                String empid = data[0];
                String name=data[1];
                String lname=data[2];
                String ccode = data[3].substring(0, 2);
                String newData=empid+","+name+","+lname+","+ccode+"\n";
                bw.write(newData);
                bw.newLine();
            }
        }

        bw.close();
        if (!original.delete()) {
            System.out.println("Could not delete file");
            return;
        }

        // Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
        if (!tempFile.renameTo(original))
            System.out.println("Could not rename file");
```

Comment: Instead of using substring, is it possible to replace each country code with something else? For example, how can I change `USA` to `US` without using substring, or replace `IND` with `IN`

Comment: You can use replace method like String ccode = data[3].replace(data[3].toCharArray()[data[3].length()-1], '\0');